# vim: copy and paste text without looking into the line number

Tags: linux, vim

For example, I want to copy the line 5~15 and paste it in another place. I find several methods:

1. Move your cursor to the line 5, then `11yy`, and `p`
2. Command: `5,15y` and `p`
3. Ctrl + V, select the block within line 5~15, then go the place you want to paste in, leave enough blank lines for pasting(or it would be overlap with the current text), and `p`

I'm not satisfied with any of these methods, for method 1 and 2, I would have to bother to see the line number or count how many lines I want to copy, when the text covers many lines, it becomes quite tricky. For method 3, I would have to allow enough space ahead, which also acquires me to count the lines I want to paste. So is there any method that is just like method 3, only that I don't need to leave enough space beforehand?

---

EDIT: Method 2, the original `5,15yy` is wrong. Has been corrected.

Comment: You might want to clarify number 2. It doesn't work in normal or command mode.

Comment: @echristopherson Sorry, it's wrong. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method similar to your 3. would be:

1. Go to Line-5, then `V15Gy` or `V10jy` or `Vjjj...jy` (`V` is Visual Mode linewise. You can see your selected lines without bodhering about the line numbers)
2. Go to Line-40(or somewhere else) and `p`. That would put the yanked lines after Line-40. Or use `P` to put it before Line-40.

Or you can use the Ex-command `:t` (the same as `:copy` but shorter)

`:5,15t 40`

Answer (score 3):

When you want to copy entire lines, use *linewise visual mode*, entered via `V`. With this, the register contents will shift existing lines automatically when pasted, unlike the *blockwise* selection you've used via `<C-V>`.

You can also use `:put` to paste as whole lines (even if you've (mistakenly) make a blockwise selection). For more such tricks and handy mappings, there's my [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355).